# How to sort dictionary keys by their appearance in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know that a dictionary is an unordered data type, but that it can be sorted alphabetically with the `sorted()` function. However, I wonder if it is definitely impossible to sort the dictionary's keys *by their appearance in a file*. For example, I want to extract fruit names from a txt-file and map them to the line number and timestamp. The resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
mydict = {
    'orange': [['1', '00:00:03,950'],  # 'fruit': [['line number', 'timestamp']]
         ['9', '00:00:24,030'], 
         ['11', '00:00:29,640']],  
    'cherry': [['20', '00:00:54,449']],  
    'apple': [['14', '00:00:38,629']], 
    'banana': [['2', '00:00:06,840'],  
          ['3', '00:00:09,180'], 
          ['4', '00:00:10,830']],
}
```

Now, I would like to sort the keys by their appearance in the file, i.e. ascending by their *line number* being the value's first list item.

So the desired output would be:

```
{'orange': [['1', '00:00:03,950'],
         ['9', '00:00:24,030'], 
         ['11', '00:00:29,640']], 
 'banana': [['2', '00:00:06,840'],  # changed
          ['3', '00:00:09,180'], 
          ['4', '00:00:10,830']]} 
 'apple': [['14', '00:00:38,629']],
 'cherry': [['20', '00:00:54,449']]}  # changed
```

If you consider this as a stupid question because this is not possible due to the dictionary's unordered nature, you can just comment this and I will then remove this question. However, I am thankful for any help and clarification.

Comment: Python 3 dictionaries are sorted ;) You can just insert any key, and the order will be kept.

Comment: Do you know that the `sorted` function has a `key` parameter?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco That won't help if the desired order is different from the insertion order.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco - CPython 3.6+ dictionaries are sorted.

Comment: ```print(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1][0][0])))```, the output is exactly like you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the `list` associated with each fruit, you could do the following:

```
>>> mydict = {k : sorted(v, key=lambda x : int(x[0])) for k, v in mydict.items()}
>>> mydict

{'orange': [['1', '00:00:03,950'],
            ['9', '00:00:24,030'],
            ['11', '00:00:29,640']],
 'cherry': [['20', '00:00:54,449']],
 'apple': [['14', '00:00:38,629']],
 'banana': [['2', '00:00:06,840'],
            ['3', '00:00:09,180'],
            ['4', '00:00:10,830']]}
```

This is iterating over the key value pairs of the dictionary, and sorting the elements of each value by the `int` of their first element.

But to be clear, as of Python 3.7, the normal `dict` is [ordered](http://gandenberger.org/2018/03/10/ordered-dicts-vs-ordereddict/#:%7E:text=Standard%20dict%20objects%20preserve%20order,makes%20the%20OrderedDict%20class%20obsolete.).  So here, you see that the fruit names are appearing in the same ordered they were created - in earlier Python this wasn't the case.

You also say you want to sort the *keys* (the fruit names), but it looks like you want to sort the *values* (the line numbers and timestamps).  If you want to additionally sort the fruit names, you could throw `sorted` on the call to get the items:

```
>>> mydict = {k : sorted(v, key=lambda x : int(x[0])) for k, v in sorted(mydict.items())}
>>> mydict

{'apple': [['14', '00:00:38,629']],
 'banana': [['2', '00:00:06,840'],
            ['3', '00:00:09,180'],
            ['4', '00:00:10,830']],
 'cherry': [['20', '00:00:54,449']],
 'orange': [['1', '00:00:03,950'],
            ['9', '00:00:24,030'],
            ['11', '00:00:29,640']]}

# now mydict's keys are in alphabetical order, and its values are also ordered by line number
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I guess you're right by saying that I would rather want to sort the values instead of the keys... Sorry, it has been a long workday which is probably why I got stuck with the "key idea". So thanks for pointing this out!